# Bot Framework Version isn't updated

Tags: botframework

We use Microsoft Bot Framework and Node.js application.
`botbuilder` dependency has been updated in `package.json`. However on https://dev.botframework.com/bots?id=bot_id the `Bot Framework Version` is still an old one.
Any ideas why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framework version references just the REST API version, not the SDK version. When we brought Skype & Bot Framework API's together we jumped to V3.0.